# footer is fixed on viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, footer

I have footer which I am using with a viewpager. When I swipe left or right the footer also swipe left or right. I want footer to be fixed on each page on viewpager. Any idea to make footer stay fixed even when I swipe Pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a master layout. which has viewpager and footer 
And load the fragments to the view pager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--Header-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerTextViewe"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:gravity="center" />
<!--View Pager-->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/createTeamViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp" />
    <!--Footer-->   
    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/NextButton"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:hint="Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MyMatches extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_teams_master);
    iniUI();
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

`

```
void iniUI() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
}
void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    CustomViewPagerFragmentAdapter adapter = new CustomViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    CustomListViewFragment fragment1= CustomListViewFragment.newInstance();
    CustomListViewFragment fragment2= CustomListViewFragment.newInstance();
    adapter.addFragment(fragment1, "Current");
    adapter.addFragment(fragment2, "Past");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.mymatchesitem));
    //toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.MyMatchesActivityTitle));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(MyMatches.this);
        }
    });
}
```

}